# How to make PHP variable name of SQL table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have an html form  in which a person fills an input field. The input field will then be sent to the PHP form handler. The form handler will then process  it and the variable input in the html form will then become the name of an SQL table. Everything is okay except that part of making the variable the name of SQL table.

Look at my code:

```
<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);?>
<?php $title =$_POST['myfile']?>
<?php $info =$_POST['info']?>
<?php $tags =$_POST['tags']?>
<?php $category =$_POST['category']?>
<?php $allowcomments =$_POST['allowcomments']?>
<?php $flagging =$_POST['flagging']?>
<?php $visibility =$_POST['visibility']?>

<?php $date =$_POST['date']?>
<?php $name =$_POST['name']?>
<?php $size =$_POST['size']?>
<?php $type =$_POST['type']?>
<?php $path =$_POST['path']?>
<?php $sub =$_POST['sub']?>
<?php $cap =$_POST['cap']?>


<?php
$servername='localhost';
$username='root';
$password='you aint gonna know my password!!';
$dbname = "galaxall";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
@mysql_select_db('galaxall');

?>

<?php $title =$_POST['myfile']?><br>
<?php echo $title?><br>
<?php echo $info?><br>
<?php echo $tags?><br>
<?php echo $category?><br>
<?php echo $allowcomments?><br>
<?php echo $visibility?><br>
<?php echo $flagging?><br>

<?php echo $cap ?>
<?php  echo $date ?>
<?php  echo $name ?>
<?php echo $size ?>
<?php  echo $type ?>
<?php echo $sub ?>
<?php echo $cap ?>

<?php $file=$_POST['myfile']?>

<?php

$sql="INSERT INTO `galaxall_uploads` (`ID`, `Title`, `Producer`, `Description`, `Tags`, `Type`, `Category`, `Allow comments`, `Flag offensive comments`, `Date`, `Visibility`,`Size`,`Path`,`Subtitles_source`,`Captions_source`) VALUES (NULL, '$title', '', '$info', '$tags', '$type', '$category', '$allowcomments', '$flagging', '$date', '$visibility','$size','$path','$cap','$sub')";
$sql2="CREATE TABLE $title `Comments` ( `ID` BIGINT(255) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT , `Commenter` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL , `Comment` TEXT NOT NULL , `Date/time` DATETIME NOT NULL , `Likes` BIGINT(255) NOT NULL , `Dislikes` BIGINT(255) NOT NULL , `Replies number` BIGINT(255) NOT NULL , PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)) ENGINE = InnoDB;";

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 


if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}


?>
<?php
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 


if ($conn->query($sql2) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql2 . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}


?>


<html>


The file has been uploaded

</html>
```

The var $title has been declared and I an even echo it.But when i try to make it the name of the table(sql2),I get the error

```
2018-07-20 New record created successfullyError: CREATE TABLE title `Commentsss` ( `ID` BIGINT(255) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT , `Commenter` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL , `Comment` TEXT NOT NULL , `Date/time` DATETIME NOT NULL , `Likes` BIGINT(255) NOT NULL , `Dislikes` BIGINT(255) NOT NULL , `Replies number` BIGINT(255) NOT NULL , PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)) ENGINE = InnoDB;
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '`Commentsss` ( `ID` BIGINT(255) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT , `Commenter` VARCHAR(25' at line 1 The file has been uploaded
```

So how do I make a PHP variable the name of a table?

Comment: `Date/time` is a valid column name?

Comment: before i take a deeper look into your code, are you sure you want people to be able to create new tables?

Comment: yes..it is a date/time type

Comment: nope - that's the issue, @kerbholz

Comment: Christopher Supertramp...yes i think so or how will i store the details of comments when they comment a video

Comment: @TItoAmoo see my edit for a suggestion on a better db design approach

Comment: You are extremely abusing use of php tags. You do not need to open and close php in every single line. Open in one line, close it in last line in a block of php lines. Also learn about escaping characters and concatenation so you will not need to close php just to add one html tag, to be specific i mean lines with <br> tags. Otherwise your code looks ugly and definitely is harder to read.

Comment: Another suggestion from me would be avoid spaces in you naming convention. And avoid using illegal characters as well while naming a column or table. Also check the datatypes as well. I dont thing likes column needs a bigint. These are the small things but makes a lot of difference in the performance while handling big data.

Comment: @ spectatorx I'm 12 yrs.....thanks

Comment: @ spectatorx how does that affect it?I'm the only one coding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i don't want to get in your database design but the error you are facing is about string concatenation and an issue on having a space in the table name:

```
$sql2="CREATE TABLE `$title_Comments` ( `ID` BIGINT(255) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT , `Commenter` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL , `Comment` TEXT NOT NULL , `Date/time` DATETIME NOT NULL , `Likes` BIGINT(255) NOT NULL , `Dislikes` BIGINT(255) NOT NULL , `Replies number` BIGINT(255) NOT NULL , PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)) ENGINE = InnoDB;";
```

this will fix the error you mention in your question

EDIT: looking at the comments I can suggest you to have a single table for comments where you store the comment, the id of the user that does the comment and the id of the video they are commenting on. As I said, no need for a custom table each time

Comment: perfect so smart

Comment: If this solves your issue consider marking answer as solving your question with the thick mark

Comment: ok but it was not reallly your answer but your advice that made be tick it